# Using GET/ filename.html HTTP ......... python serve client

Tags: python, http, server, get, client

Hopefully I can make this somewhat clear. I have to create a server and client in python that sends HTTP GET request to each other. Now I created a basic server/client program and now my goal is to send the server a HTTP GET request(from an html file I have saved) and the server to display the content.
Example Server would display something like
Date:
Content Length:
content Type:

As of now when I run the client and type GET / filename.html HTTP/1.1\n\r the server does not display. When I type that exact command in just a Linux shell it displays perfectly. How can I do this in a client and server. Hopefully this makes sense. Here is my client and server.

```
 #CLIENT
import socket
import sys

host = socket.gethostname()    
port = 12345                   # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
print(s.recv(1024))
inpt = input("type")
b = bytes(inpt, 'utf-8') #THIS SENDS BUT SERVER DOESDNT RECIEVE
s.sendall(b)
print("Message Sent")
```

---

```
#SERVERimport socket
import sys
host = ''        # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
port = 12345     # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
while True:
  c, addr = s.accept()
  print("Connection accepted from " + repr(addr[1]))
  c.send(b"Server Approved")
  print(repr(addr[1]) + ":" + c.recv(1024).decode("UTF-8"))
  c.close()
```

I want to type something like this to my server and display its content
GET / google.com HTTP/1.1\r\n

Answer (score 0):

The error message is so straightforward, just read it to fix the code that doesn't work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
print(repr(addr[1]) + ":" + c.recv(1024))
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Add `.decode("utf-8")`:

```
print(repr(addr[1]) + ":" + c.recv(1024).decode("utf-8"))
```

And more clear is to use [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) instead of [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr). You can read about the differences between these two here: [Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python).

```
print(str(addr[1]) + ":" + c.recv(1024).decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Even with the .decode imputed I'm still getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: My bad, addr[1] is an `int` so either `str()` or `repr()` is necessary.

Comment: Hmm both still don't seem to work. But thank you for the .decode portion it makes sense to change the byte into a string

Comment: Please update the question with the error or/and description of the problem you have right now, so I can help.

Comment: just updated code and displayed the HTTP GET method I want to type in and display

Comment: you mean that you want '\r\n' appended to each of the messages sent from the client? and displayed exactly like that on the server?